# Access http server on port 8080 from android tablet using 3G wireless network

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which connects to a http server on port 8080. The application is working fine on the emulator. But when I try to use the application from the real tablet device, I will not be able to access the http server.
I used the following:
- Both of the devices are connected to the same wireless network using 3G router.
- The android application connects to http server using the IP address 192.168.0.4

Comment: What client do you use to access the server? Can you show your code?